# how to generate large scale data set in Json file

Tags: angularjs, json, database

where i can find or how to generate large dataset of basic information(for example name,family,age,address) in Json file about 100,000, without duplication and Preferably be free and The data are random . for example see this link :
https://www.mockaroo.com/
this website for More than 1,000 will be paid But I'm looking for free solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code where you can customize your json object

**JS code**

```
  var data = [];
  var n = 0;
  // looping for 100000 
  for (n; n < 100000; n++) {
  // creating object here
    var obj = {
      name: 'name_' + n,
      family: 'family_' + n,
      age: 'age_' + n,
      address: 'address_' + n
    };

    // pushing each object here in array
    data.push(obj);
  }

  // your data is ready here so check in console
  console.log(data);
```

This will generate the expected json array.
Here is link[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gz5fxdme/2/)

Comment: can you explain this code in plunkr please,I want to see output

Comment: added link please check

Comment: i looking for random variable for example see this link :
https://www.mockaroo.com/
this website for More than 1,000 will be paid But I'm looking for free solutions.